# How to get basic NFT transaction details?

Tags: ether, nft, web3.py

This seems like a pretty common need, but I haven't found a great solution.  Does anyone know of an API to get the details of an ETH transfer from a transaction hash?

For example, this transaction: 0x017834f1951bbaadedf04fe4318a7850ab44bc2ffdb7f1f94320860ac1cf68fd

On etherscan, you get a detailed page of what was transfered (token address and ID), who the buyer was, who the seller was, and the amount paid in exchange.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x017834f1951bbaadedf04fe4318a7850ab44bc2ffdb7f1f94320860ac1cf68fd

Does anyone know of a service (I'd gladly pay for!) that reliably does this?  I have coded up my own solution using web3.py and infura, but I am decoding the logs pretty manually and its a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Moralis API might help you in your case. It has an API endpoint to get the [NFT contract transfers](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-nft-contract-transfers) which can provide you with the transfers happened on a smart contract and also an endpoint to get the [internal transactions of a transaction](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-internal-transactions) which can be helpful to read the internal transactions that happened during an NFT transfer.

There is also an API endpoint to get the [NFT trades from the marketplace](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/get-nft-trades) which gives you decoded data of the NFT transfer with the trade price but it currently only supports the Opensea marketplace.

There are other endpoints too are provided by Moralis that might help you in getting the data related to NFT transactions.

I hope this helps

Disclosure: I work at Moralis

Comment: Thanks!  The NFT trade endpoint seems really useful, just wish it supported other marketplaces too (as blur for example is quite popular now).

Any plans to add more?

Comment: They might add in the future depending on the demand. You can suggest it in https://roadmap.moralis.io/

Comment: IMO I think the answer reply is fine!